# select query depends on MAX function

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
Select name 
from score, student 
where student.student_id = score.student_id 
and event_id = 1
and score.score = (select MAX(score) from score where event_id = 1)
```

I test the select MAX(score) from score where event_id = 1) works, but when I try to use it like this way to find the name, it does not work fine, it does not call error just say 0 result.
I want to ask how can I get the value using this way or similar way?

Comment: Select name from score   ----- should it not be select name from student or select name and score from student

Comment: what query you try to select name then return 0 result ? can you post ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student FROM table ORDER BY MAX( score ) DESC
```